# Consider the set of all functions with domain & codomain R as a vector space over R. Is the set of basis functions countable or uncountable and why?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Consider the set of all functions with domain R and codomain R as a vector space
over R. Define a set of basis functions. Are they countable or uncountable? If so
why?

Comment: Consider the functions $f_c(x)= 1 if $x=c$ and $0$  otherwise, for all $c\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner And these span only a tiny, tiny fraction of the space in question.

Comment: I messed up the formatting.  Here's what my comment above said:  Consider the functions $f_c(x)= 1$ if $x=c$ and $0$  otherwise, for all $c\in\mathbb R$

Comment: To reiterate HagenvonEitzen's point, a span of vectors often only considers *finite* linear combinations of basis vectors.  Using the proposed basis vectors by @J.W.Tanner the only elements in the span would be those functions who have finitely many values of $x$ for which they return nonzero results and the infinitely many other values of $x$ return zero.  See [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) and [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) on wikipedia.

Comment: @JMoravitz That shows the uncountable set of delta functions aren't a basis. You need to work just a little harder to show there is no countable basis.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

A basis for that function space must be uncountable.

To see why, recall that the span of a set of vectors is the set of finite linear combinations of elements of the set.

Suppose you had a countable spanning set $S$ of functions. Then $S$ has only countably many finite subsets. The linear combinations of the functions in a finite set of functions can contain only finitely many functions $\delta_t(x)$ that are $1$ at the point $x=t$ and $0$ everywhere else.

That means that you can generate only countably many of the uncountable number of functions  $\delta_t$.

Note that the uncountable set of functions $\delta_t$   is not even close to a basis. Finite linear combinations of those functions produce only the functions that are $0$ at all but finitely many points.

Bases do exist, and they are uncountable, but there is no constructive way to describe one. Their existence depends on the axiom of choice.

Answer (score -1):

The functions $I_t(x) = \begin{cases}  1 & x =t \\0& x \neq t\end{cases}$ is clearly an independent set; there is no way to create $I_t$ for a particular $t$ from a linear combination of functions of other $t$s. Since this uncountable set can't be generated with a countable basis, the set of functions overall can't have a countable basis.

A cardinality argument also shows that the set can't have a countable basis: the set of all finite linear combinations of a countable basis has a cardinality equal to the real numbers, but the set of all functions from the real numbers to itself has a cardinality greater than the real numbers.

Comment: Both the assertions in this "answer" are false. The functions $I_t$ are nowhere near a basis. The only functions you can get with _finite_ linear combinations of these  functions are those with only a finite number of nonzero values. The second paragraph is wrong too, for different reasons.